# Is there a quick way to make multiple Illustrator swatches global?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

Global swatches are my friends. Being able to open a swatch in Illustrator, change its colour values and have my art change along is invaluable.

I know I can change a swatch to global by opening the swatch and checking the 'Global' box:

[image]

How do I do this for multiple swatches at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select multiple swatches in your swatch panel holding either Shift (if they're near each other) or Control/Command if they're not.

Then on the top right drop down panel menu can click on Swatch Properties and click Global to set them all at once.

[image]

Comment: You can just click the Swatch Options button on the panel, no need to open the menu ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go into the top right drop down panel menu and click on Add Used Colours.
2. Or select all objects and click on the "New Color Group" icon located at the bottom of the swatches panel. This will open a modal dialog box.*(refer to attached image).*[image: New Color Group Modal Dialog]